# rails 3 accepts nested attributes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-attributes

I am trying to use nested attributes on my user model for settings so that I can edit the user info and the setting info in a single page.  Here is my code:

User.rb

```
has_one :settings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :settings, :allow_destroy => true
attr_accessor :settings_attributes
```

views/users/registrations/edit.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :settings do |s| %>
<p>
  <%= s.label :newsletter %><br />
  <%= s.check_box :newsletter %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

This seemingly works just fine, the form is displayed properly.  However the attributes for the settings are not changed at all when I submit the form.

I am using Rails 3, and Devise created my user model.  Perhaps I am missing something that needs to go in the controller model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely caused by using plural instead of singular for setting.  Try changing to this:

**model**

```
has_one :setting
accepts_nested_attributes_for :setting, :allow_destroy => true
```

**view**

```
<%= f.fields_for :setting do |s| %>
```

What are you using the attr_accessor for?

Comment: the actual model is called settings.rb. I was using the attr_accesor because if I don't I get the following: irb(main):002:0> user.settings_attributes
NoMethodError: undefined method `settings_attributes' for #<User:0x102d7fe80>

Comment: never got it working. ended up just creating a new model and handling all of this via controller

Comment: sorry, I guess I missed your first comment.  I still think it has something to do with plural vs. singular, since your model name is plural.  But if you are content on leaving the model name as "Settings", then I think your solution is probably the way to go, in order to avoid any problems with how Rails handles this.